# problem in date column with hibernate hql query

Tags: hibernate, hql

i hav a  hql query..it gets the data used between two dates..i wriiten a query like this
from com.cod.model.Billing where datecolumn between '2011-4-4' and '2011-4-20'

but i didn't get any results from this query ..i checked out this query in mysql with sql query.there it's workng fine..but if i write same query in hql it returns null results
 can any one say what's the problem in my query.thanx in advance

Comment: It is a good practice to follow up the answers the questions posted by yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dates mentioned have to be of the type `java.util.Date` and not `String`